# .NET Xml deserialization, issue/error with xsi:type attribute

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, namespaces

VS2008, .NET Framework 3.5

We're utilizing the WebEx Xml API.  Here's a sample Xml response from their web service that I'm trying to deserialize into .NET classes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<serv:message xmlns:serv="http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service" xmlns:com="http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/common" 

xmlns:event="http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service/event"><serv:header><serv:response><serv:result>SUCCESS</serv:result><serv:gsbStatus>PRIMARY</s

erv:gsbStatus></serv:response></serv:header>
<serv:body>
<serv:bodyContent xsi:type="event:lstsummaryEventResponse" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<event:matchingRecords>
    <serv:total>2</serv:total>
    <serv:returned>2</serv:returned>
    <serv:startFrom>1</serv:startFrom>
</event:matchingRecords>
<event:event>
    <event:sessionKey>999999</event:sessionKey>
    <event:sessionName>Test Event 1</event:sessionName>
    <event:sessionType>129</event:sessionType>
    <event:hostWebExID>SomeName</event:hostWebExID>
    <event:startDate>03/28/2012 14:30:00</event:startDate>
    <event:endDate>03/28/2012 14:45:00</event:endDate>
    <event:timeZoneID>11</event:timeZoneID>
    <event:duration>15</event:duration>
    <event:description></event:description>
    <event:status>NOT_INPROGRESS</event:status>
    <event:panelists></event:panelists>
    <event:listStatus>PUBLIC</event:listStatus>
</event:event>
</serv:bodyContent>
</serv:body>
</serv:message>
```

Here's the class that we're deserializing into:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Masonite.MTier.WebEx
{
    [Serializable()]
    [XmlRoot("message", Namespace = "http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service")]
    public class lstsummaryEventResponsexx
    {
        [XmlNamespaceDeclarations]
        public XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();

        public lstsummaryEventResponsexx()
        {
            xmlns.Add("serv", "http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service");
            xmlns.Add("com", "http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/common");
            xmlns.Add("event", "http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service/event");
        }


        [XmlElement(ElementName = "header")]
        public Header header { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "body")]
        public Body body { get; set; }


        [Serializable()]
        [XmlRoot("header")]
        public class Header
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "response")]
            public Response response { get; set; }
        }


        [Serializable()]
        [XmlRoot("body")]
        [XmlInclude(typeof(lstsummaryEventResponse))]
        public class Body
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "bodyContent", Form = XmlSchemaForm.Qualified)]
            public BodyContent bodyContent { get; set; }
        }

        [Serializable()]
        public class lstsummaryEventResponse
        {

        }

        [Serializable()]
        [XmlRoot("response")]
        public class Response
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "result")]
            public string result { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "reason")]
            public string reason { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "gsbStatus")]
            public string gsbStatus { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "exceptionID")]
            public string exceptionID { get; set; }
        }


        [Serializable()]
        [XmlRoot("bodyContent")]
        public class BodyContent
        {            
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "matchingRecords", Namespace = "http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service/event")]
            public MatchingRecords matchingRecords { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "event", Namespace = "http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service/event")]
            public List<EventSummary> events { get; set; }
        }


        [Serializable()]
        [XmlRoot("matchingRecords")]
        public class MatchingRecords
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "total", Namespace = "http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service")]
            public int total { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "returned", Namespace = "http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service")]
            public int returned { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "startFrom", Namespace = "http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service")]
            public int startFrom { get; set; }
        }


        [Serializable()]
        [XmlRoot("event")]
        public class EventSummary
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "sessionKey")]
            public long sessionKey { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "sessionName")]
            public string sessionName { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "sessionType")]
            public int sessionType { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "hostWebExID")]
            public string hostWebExID { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "startDate")]
            public string startDate { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "endDate")]
            public string endDate { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "timeZoneID")]
            public int timeZoneID { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "duration")]
            public int duration { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "description")]
            public string description { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "status")]
            public string status { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "panelists")]
            public string panelists { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "listStatus")]
            public listingType listStatus { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

The error I'm receiving:

```
The specified type was not recognized: name='lstsummaryEventResponse', namespace='http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service/event', at <bodyContent xmlns='http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service'>
```

I'm not sure how to provide the type lstsummaryEventResponse for the Deserialize method.  I added another serializable class to my class above using that name, but get the same error.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BodyContent` can have the type `event:lstsummaryEventResponse` - so you have to declare the corresponding class, and then decorate the declaration of `BodyContent` as follows:

```
    [Serializable()] 
    [XmlRoot("bodyContent")] 
    [XmlInclude("lstsummaryEventResponse")]
    public class BodyContent {

    }
```

Having said that, creating C# class with a serialization corresponding to some arbitrary XML is pretty tricky, I am not sure it is right approach

Comment: Thank you, MiMo.  It seems as though the lstsummaryEventResponse class needs to be nested within the EventSummary class.   Is .net smart enough to match up event.lstsummaryEventResponse with my class EventSummary.lstsummaryEventResponse using EventSummary's XmlRoot decoration, or does it actually require my class to be named "event" (which I can't do for obvious reasons)?  I've tried nesting lstsummaryEventResponse directly under lstsummaryEventResponsexx and EventSummary, but receive the same error that I mentioned in the original post.

Comment: .NET will use the name you specified in `XmlRoot`. Class nesting does not matter, but `lstsummaryEventResponse` must derive from `BodyContent`